# Why is this argument not being passed by reference?

Tags: powershell

In powershell, the following works as expected:

```
function SetProps([ref]$variable)
{
    $variable.value += "Hello"
}

$val = New-Object Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection

SetProps ([ref]$val)

$val
```

The variable `$val` gets the "Hello" appended.

However, this example does not work:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=sample,DC=local" -Properties EmailAddress, ProxyAddresses

function SetProps([ref]$props){
    $props.Value += "Hello"
}

foreach($user in $users){
    SetProps ([ref]$user.proxyAddresses)
    $user.proxyAddresses
}
```

"Hello" does not get appended to the proxyAddresses.  Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You can make reference to variable `[ref]$variable`, but not to some arbitrary expression `[ref]($variable)`. In latter case, expression value will be stored in some internal storage, and you will get reference to that storage.